# Max.perKey(custom Comparator) returns PCollections of NullPointer

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a realtime pipeline and I want to find Max.perKey for each key in 30 minutes. I have following code.

```
Pcollection<DO> p = inputCollection
Pcollection<KV<String,DO>> p2 = windows.apply("create key with id1:id2 as key",
                MapElements.into(new TypeDescriptor<KV<String, DO>>() {})
                        .via(dO ->KV.of(Delimiters.formatWithComma(dO.id1(),
                                        dO.id2()), dO)));
Pcollection<KV<String,DO>> windowedP = windows.apply("Apply fixed window",
                Window.<KV<String, DO>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(30)))
                        .triggering(DefaultTrigger.of())
                        .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
                        .discardingFiredPanes());

Pcollection<KV<String,DO>> maxKV = windowsKV.apply("Find latest in window", Max.perKey(new WindowComparator()));

Pcollection<DO> maxDO = maxKV.apply("Create value", Values.create())

PCollection<Mutation> spannerMuations =  maxP.apply("Transform to spanner mutation", MapElements
                .into(new TypeDescriptor<Mutation>() {})
                .via((SerializableFunction<DO, Mutation>) dO ->
                        dO.newUpsertMutation())); ---> This steps say d0 is nullpointer.
```

Custom Comparator:

```
static class WindowComparator implements Comparator<DO>, Serializable {
    @Override
    public int compare(final DO dO1,  final DO dO2) {
        return dO1.getTimestamp().compareTo(dO2.getTimestamp());
    }
}
```

I saw dO.newUpsertMutation giving `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.exabeam.ng.beam.spanner.dao.DO.newUpsertMutation()" because "dO" is null` in two scenarios.

One time I saw it while draining the job and another time when pipeline wrote 450K mutation successfully and then started throwing tons of these errors. For this I saw Max.perKey outputting more elements:

[Max.perkey outputting more elements than input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eICpk.png)

I don't understand why this is happening?

Comment: Is there any possibility that Max.perKey will return a null value?